# Webdev: Open Source font and legal issues

Tags: law, license

I use the open source font Metropolis as main font for my webpages.

However, apparently there has been a legal issue with similarities to Gotham.

See https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/metropolis-font-repo-missing/69415 for more infos. The author Chris Simpson had to put his Github repo to private.

I wondered if there now are any legal consequences for new and old projects which actively use this font. I actually still see it in use of many big players too, i.e. https://www.vmware.com

Any ideas?